# Finding a running stored procedure to kill it

Tags: t-sql

```
select session_id,*  
from sys.dm_exec_requests handle   
outer apply sys.fn_get_sql(handle.sql_handle) spname  
where spname.text like '%some-procedure-name%'
```

this gives me a result, says the status is "running" but the session_id value matches the spid from sp_who2 for my own id.
I am not running that procedure.
Is sessionid the same as a spid reported from sp_who2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above will return all spids that are running queries that match on the lookup value, including itself.  You can modify your code to exclude itself by adding:

```
AND r.session_id <> @@SPID
```